# Create WiFi hotspot with web access point

Tags: wireless-networking, isp

I want to setup a WiFi network with access through a web interface. Essentially people would be asked to enter a username/password and their session would be valid for X minutes after which they'd be logged out.

I am capable of quite a few programming/scripting languages, but browsing through router settings I don't see how to/where hosted/etc. the web interface/session handling comes in.

Please push me the right direction.

Comment: What you're looking for is called 'captive portal'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Journeyman Geek was correct in saying that you need to use what is called a captive portal.

1. Buy a wireless AP with captive portal support built in or install DD-WRT on another AP
2. Install a captive portal program on a server that will handle the users. A quick google search found this suite http://dev.wifidog.org/ It may be of use.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This depends wildly on what router you have. The more "commercial" ones support this than consumer ones. Although you can put DD-WRT on a few consumer ones, and that has some provisions for a "hotspot". I've never tried it though.

EDIT: You might try this link some advice about installing DD-WRT: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=670900

Comment: My router is Cisco E4200. I can't find anything in the settings that would look alike. It does allow guest access, though, that's far from the same.