# Issue related to wireless internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create WiFi hotspot with web access point](https://superuser.com/questions/436762/create-wifi-hotspot-with-web-access-point)

I have Internet cybercafe, and I have wireless internet connection.

If any customer comes to surf, and he types `www.google.com` he should redirect to my company's page to enter a password to open `www.google.com`, if password is correct then and only then page redirect to `www.google.com`

My question is how to trap my wireless internet connection to redirect user to my company's page.?

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808589/issue-related-to-wireless-internet-connection

Answer (score 1):

You have to install and configure your DNS server (bind) and DHCPD server. Create two local networks, one for non-authenticated (as default), one for authenticated. In the first network, filter internet access and resolve all domain requests using DNS server to your company IP address. They'll be redirected to your website whatever then type. Once they're activated (logged in), your DHCPD should send them a new address (IP in the authenticated network) where they have access to the internet.